# If/ElseIf Statements only working for the first if statement

Tags: vba, loops, if-statement, charts

My If (ElseIf) statements seem to only for the first If statement. I'm not sure what I'm missing here. This is for a chart that needs boundaries that change based on the cell values C3:D11. The chart is essentially two overlapping graphs, which is why i have a secondary axes value. Both axes need to change during the IfElse section.

```
Sub Pyramid()

       Dim cht As Chart
       Set cht = Worksheets("AP-Chart").ChartObjects("Chart 4").Chart
       For Each cell In Range("C3:D11")


        If cell.Value < -15 Then
            cht.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = -20
            cht.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).MinimumScale = -20
        ElseIf cell.Value > 15 Then
            cht.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 20
            cht.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).MaximumScale = 20
        ElseIf cell.Value < -20 Then
            cht.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = -30
            cht.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).MinimumScale = -30
        ElseIf cell.Value > 20 Then
            cht.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 30
            cht.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).MaximumScale = 30
        ElseIf cell.Value < -30 Then
            cht.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = -40
            cht.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).MinimumScale = -40
        ElseIf cell.Value > 30 Then
            cht.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 40
            cht.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).MaximumScale = 40
        ElseIf cell.Value < -40 Then
            cht.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = -50
            cht.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).MinimumScale = -50
        ElseIf cell.Value > 40 Then
            cht.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 50
            cht.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).MaximumScale = 50
        End If
       Next cell

       ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 4").Activate
       ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
       myPDF = "\\stchsfs\arboari$\Profile-Data\Desktop\Export Trial1\c1-" & Sheets("AP").Range("C" & i + 3).Value2 & ".pdf"
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=myPDF, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
    i = i + 1
     Next counter

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: Consider a `Select Case`, where you can use `Case -20 to -15` style statements to describe the ranges. `if ... elseif` statements can get confusing and hard to maintain (as you have just found out!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple, your if else statements are wrong.

-20 its lower than -15 so it always do the thing inside the first If.

You should do something like:

```
If cell.Value < -15 And cell.Value > -20 Then
    cht.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = -20
    cht.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).MinimumScale = -20
ElseIf cell.Value < -20 And cell.Value > -30 Then
    //do stuff here
```

And you continue like that. You should do the same thing with the positive values, and I think you are not considering the values -20,-30, etc (because you are excluding them).